# How to use Salesforce sharing rules for users with profiles?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to use sharing rules for users WITH profiles. Is there any use of them if users have profiles? Or does the profile completely override record access so that i can forget about sharing rules?

I'm in situation where ALL my users have profiles. What I wanted to do was to GRANT "Edit" access for certain records to certain user groups. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user's role dictates which records they can SEE, while their profile dictates what they can DO with those records. Typically the only case where the profile overrides the role is if their assigned profile contains one of the "View All" or "Modify All" permissions on an object.

For example, if you have a role hierarchy set up that divides different branches of your organization, it may be useful to hide the data between these branches. In this case, you would want to set the org-wide default to Read Only, and provide sharing rules that grant access on an as-needed basis (these sharing rules would be based on a user's role, public groups, or queues that they belong to).

Sharing rules also allow you to specify whether you want to grant the ability to edit records or simply view them. So in your case, you will want to create a sharing rule granting edit access on records owned by one group of users to your second group of users.

See the [Overview of Sharing Settings](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/managing_the_sharing_model.htm) for more information.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I realized that myself actually. The problem was with confusing Salesforce admin UI.

Even though I wasn't able to edit records, the fields on record's page were editable, so I thought I could modify the record, even though there was an error message when I pressed "Save".

This ridiculousness wasted me at least 2 hours!